# Merge corresponding elements of 2 lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

List 1:

```
['buying','maint']
```

List 2:

```
[['med', 'vhigh', 'low', 'high'],['med', 'small', 'big']]
```

Expected_output:

```
[['buying_med', 'buying_vhigh','buying_low','buying_high'],['maint_med','maint_small','maint_big']]
```

Please let mw know on how to do this in python 3.

Comment: Have you tried some approach?

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service, you should say what you have tried and what has failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a homework problem so I will only give a suggestion to push you in the right direction. Start with trying to implement a solution with 2 for loops. If you want to improve your answer, take a look at [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: And it was accepted as a valid answer? Shameless from who asks!

Comment: I appreciate your not spoonfeeding OP with their homework, but it would be even better if you gave the same answer in a comment:) That way roomba can eat this question in a few days (now your accepted answer is blocking the auto-deletion process). This is a very good reason why one should not give actual answers (rather than comments) to effortless/worthless questions. No harm done, I'm just informing you so that you can consider this in the future, if you wish:)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the process involved in removing these types of questions. I just assumed these questions got downvoted and not viewed that often. I never thought about this problem but the auto-deletion script makes sense. Sorry for blocking the question. I learned something new from your comment.